# Replace content of matching XML tags

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot

I have an XML string. I want to replace all the text contents enclosed with certain tags.

For Example:

Sample Case 1:

- Input:

  ```
  <newPassword>SOME_NEW_PASSWORD</newPassword>
  <oldPasscode>SOME_OLD_PASSWORD</oldPasscode>
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  <newPassword>**HIDDEN**</newPassword>
  <oldPasscode>**HIDDEN**</oldPasscode>
  ```

Sample Case 2:

- Input:

  ```
  <password>SOME_NEW_CODE</password>
  <passcode>SOME_OLD_CODE</passcode>
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  <password>**HIDDEN**</password>
  <passcode>**HIDDEN**</passcode>
  ```

So if the XML tag contains `password` or `passcode`, then replace its content with `**HIDDEN**`.

I have tried using regex and replace all occurrences like below:

```
String MASK = "**HIDDEN**";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)([^>])(?=<\/\wpass[word|code]\w*>)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
atcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<password>SOME_NEW_CODE</password><passcode>SOME_OLD_CODE</passcode>");
boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
if (matchFound) {
    System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll(MASK));
}
```

The output is coming as : `<newPassword>**HIDDEN****HIDDEN**</newPassword>`

It replaces twice.

Comment: Like this? `<(newpassword|(?:old)?passcode|password)>.*?</\1>` https://regex101.com/r/EY7Fmv/1 Can the password contain `<` or `>`?

Comment: If the XML tag contain password or password in its name, then replace its content.

Comment: Like this `<([^<>\s]*pass(?:word|code)[^<>]*)>.*?</\1>` https://regex101.com/r/0J2pF2/1 But the password might contain `<` or `>`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think it could be anything among `newPassword`, `newPasscode`, `oldPassword`, `oldPasscode`, `password` and `passcode`. Are these combinations a possibility @Subhakant Priyadarsan?

Comment: The above regex is selecting only the tag. We need the content here.

Comment: The regex selects the tags, and in the replacement uses `<$1>**HIDDEN**</$1>` So the replacement value will be `<newPassword>**HIDDEN**</newPassword>`

Comment: Yes, these combinations are possible. 
(?i)([^>]*)(?=<\/\w*pass[word|code]\w*>)
https://regex101.com/r/EY7Fmv/1

The above regex works, but while calling repace all, the output is coming like below.
<newPassword>**HIDDEN****HIDDEN**</newPassword>

It replaces twice.

Comment: @SubhakantPriyadarsan See https://ideone.com/yC27Ng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?i)([^>]+)(?=<\/\w*pass(?:code|word)\w*>)
```

Thanks @oliver_t and @Nikolas. I have taken references from your regex. And the above regex works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

In your pattern `[word|code]` is a character class matching one of the listed characters. If you want to match either word or code you can use an alternation `(?:word|code)`

A pattern to match `pass` followed by `word` or `code` (assuming that `<` and `>` are valid characters for a password)

```
<([^<>\s]*pass(?:word|code)[^<>\s]*)>.*?</\1>
```

- `<` Match `<`
- `([^<>\s]*pass(?:word|code)[^<>\s]*)` Match `password` or `passcode` between optional chars other than `<` `>` or whitespace chars
- `>` Match `>`
- `.*?` Match as least as possble characters
- `</\1>` Match `</` followed by a backreference to group 1 (matching up the element name) and `>`

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/yC27Ng) or a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0J2pF2/1)

In the replacement use `**HIDDEN**` between the value of capture group 1 in brackets `<$1>**HIDDEN**</$1>`

**Note** that this matches xml elements for this specific format. It does not take the validity of any structure into account.

```
String regex = "<([^<>\\s]*pass(?:word|code)[^<>]*)>.*?</\\1>";
String string = "<newPassword>SOME_NEW_PASSWORD</newPassword>\n"
+ "<oldPasscode>SOME_OLD_PASSWORD</oldPasscode>\n"
+ "<password>SOME_NEW_CODE</password>\n"
+ "<passcode>SOME_OLD_CODE</passcode>";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("<$1>**HIDDEN**</$1>"));
```

Output

```
<newPassword>**HIDDEN**</newPassword>
<oldPasscode>**HIDDEN**</oldPasscode>
<password>**HIDDEN**</password>
<passcode>**HIDDEN**</passcode>
```

---

If there can only be word chars in the tag, and no `<` or `>` in the password:

```
<(\w*pass(?:word|code)\w*)>[^<>]*</\1>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BjnCQP/1)

Comment: The output is coming as below.
```
**HIDDEN**
**HIDDEN**
**HIDDEN**
**HIDDEN**
```

Comment: @SubhakantPriyadarsan Did you check the example code? https://ideone.com/yC27Ng

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to create a generic method which can do this replacement in case you need to use some other tag. It could be implemented something like this.

```
public String replaceTextBetweenTag(
    final String input,
    final String tag,
    final String mask
) {
    final String openingTag = String.format("<%s>", tag);
    final String endTag = String.format("</%s>", tag);
    return input.replaceAll(String.format("(%s)[^&]*(%s)",openingTag,endTag), openingTag + mask + endTag);
}
```

If there are multiple in which text needs to be replaced, it could be used like this

```
public String replaceTextBetweenTags(
    final String input,
    final List<String> tags,
    final String mask
) {
    String newOutput = input;
    for(final String tag : tags){
        newOutput = replaceTextBetweenTag(input, tag, mask);
    }
    return newOutput;
}
```

So in your case simple solution would be

```
replaceTextBetweenTags("<newPassword>SOME_NEW_PASSWORD</newPassword>\n" +
                               "<oldPasscode>SOME_OLD_PASSWORD</oldPasscode>",
                           List.of("newPassword", "oldPasscode"),
                           "**HIDDEN**"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't want to use Regex for anything based on XML tags (including HTML of course). Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747/3764965) and [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/3764965).

The simplest Regex to satisfy the behavior might look like this (demo at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DFgAlC/2) including substitution):

```
<(?<tagName>[a-z]*[Pp]ass(?:code|word))>([^<]*)<\/\k<tagName>>
```

So, in Java, a minimal and reproducible sample might look like this:

```
String xml = "<newPassword>SOME_NEW_PASSWORD</newPassword>" +
            "<oldPasscode>SOME_OLD_PASSWORD</oldPasscode>" +
            "<password>SOME_NEW_CODE</password>" +
            "<passcode>SOME_OLD_CODE</passcode>" +
            "<nope>VALUE</nope>";

String hidden = xml.replaceAll(
        "<(?<tagName>[a-z]*[Pp]ass(?:code|word))>[^<]*<\\/\\k<tagName>>",
        "<${tagName}>**HIDDEN**<\\/${tagName}>");
```

Alternatively (assuming the `xml` variable existence):

```
String xml = // your xml

String regex = "<(?<tagName>[a-z]*[Pp]ass(?:code|word))>[^<]*<\\/\\k<tagName>>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
String hidden = pattern
            .matcher(xml)
            .replaceAll("<${tagName}>**HIDDEN**<\\/${tagName}>");
```

- In Java Regex `(?<tagName>MATCH_ME)` defines a named group matching `MATCH_ME`
- In Java Regex `\\k<tagName>` refers to the already named group (here `MATCH_ME`)
- In Java replacement `${tagName}` refers to the named group captured from the Regex.

If you pretty-print the output, the result looks like (I used the `nope` element to demonstrate keeping the original value):

```
<newPassword>**HIDDEN**</newPassword>
<oldPasscode>**HIDDEN**</oldPasscode>
<password>**HIDDEN**</password>
<passcode>**HIDDEN**</passcode>
<nope>VALUE</nope>
```

**Note:** Remember you might need some modifications depending on how much strict the Regex pattern should be. If possible, use a proper XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

Your RegEx is just missing several cardinalities:

```
([^>])+(?=<\/\w*pass(word|code)\w*)
      ^        ^                 ^
```

Comment: It selects <passcod>SOME_OLD_CODE</passcod>

Comment: Oh yes, you are totally right. It must be round brackets. Edited.